# How to add each image into <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of image in a parent div (.post-sl) and I want to add class  to each image.
How to do with jQuery or Javascript ?!
Thanks!

```
<div class="post-sl">
    <img src="image-link-01.png" alt="">
    <img src="image-link-02.png" alt="">
    <img src="image-link-03.png" alt="">
    <img src="image-link-04.png" alt="">
    <img src="image-link-05.png" alt="">
</div>
```

The result I want:

```
<div class="post-sl">
    <div class="addDiv">
        <img src="image-link-01.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="addDiv">
        <img src="image-link-02.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="addDiv">
        <img src="image-link-03.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="addDiv">
        <img src="image-link-04.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to do this:

```js
$('.post-sl img').wrap('<div class="addDiv"></div>');
```

```css
img {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
} 

.addDiv {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-sl">
  <img src="image-link-01.png" alt="">
  <img src="image-link-02.png" alt="">
  <img src="image-link-03.png" alt="">
  <img src="image-link-04.png" alt="">
  <img src="image-link-05.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Note the CSS above is only to make the output more visible.

Comment: Url of the doc there : http://api.jquery.com/wrap/ (Don't know if it was better to edit the post or put a comment, so I putted it as a comment)

Comment: Thanks @KévinHuang

Comment: Many many thank you! it work like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Using native js you can create a wrapper function

```js
function createWrapper(parentSelector) {
  let elem = document.querySelector(parentSelector);
  let getChildren = elem.querySelectorAll('img');
  elem.innerHTML = '';
  getChildren.forEach(function(item) {
    let crtElem = document.createElement('div');
    crtElem.setAttribute('class', 'addDiv');
    crtElem.appendChild(item);
    elem.appendChild(crtElem)
  })
}
createWrapper('.post-sl')
```

```css
.addDiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-sl">
  <img src="image-link-01.png" alt="">
  <img src="image-link-02.png" alt="">
  <img src="image-link-03.png" alt="">
  <img src="image-link-04.png" alt="">
  <img src="image-link-05.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use wrap() function

`$('image-link).wrap('<div class='addDiv'></div>')`